# Glassfish4 throw exception when I declare validation.xml file on classpath

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, classpath, glassfish-4, hibernate-validator

I've tried to declare a custom validator for @NotNull constraint and Glassfish4 throw this exception when find /META-INF/validation.xml. Project works fine if I omit this file.

```
Exception while dispatching an event
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton not set for WebappClassLoader(delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)
at   org.glassfish.weld.ACLSingletonProvider$ACLSingleton.get(ACLSingletonProvider.java:110)
at org.jboss.weld.Container.instance(Container.java:54)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.shutdown(WeldBootstrap.java:644)
at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.doBootstrapShutdown(WeldDeployer.java:309)
at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:220)
at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:493)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.executeCommand(CommandResource.java:396)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.execCommandSimpInMultOut(CommandResource.java:234)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:125)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:91)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:346)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:341)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:224)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:198)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:946)
at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:331)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.JerseyContainerCommandService$3.service(JerseyContainerCommandService.java:165)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:181)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
         ]]

           [2014-06-09T19:37:52.476+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [AS-WEB-CORE-00108]               [javax.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=32 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1402335472476] [levelValue: 1000] [[
              ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
            org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:          java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:                 javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed             object for class: class org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener
                  at            org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5864)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2278)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1924)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:497)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.executeCommand(CommandResource.java:396)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.execCommandSimpInMultOut(CommandResource.java:234)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:125)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:91)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:346)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:341)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:224)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:198)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:946)
at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:331)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.JerseyContainerCommandService$3.service(JerseyContainerCommandService.java:165)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:181)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
                          Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addListener(StandardContext.java:3270)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addApplicationListener(StandardContext.java:2476)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.TomcatDeploymentConfig.configureApplicationListener(TomcatDeploymentConfig.java:251)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.TomcatDeploymentConfig.configureWebModule(TomcatDeploymentConfig.java:110)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModuleContextConfig.start(WebModuleContextConfig.java:266)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:486)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:163)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5861)
... 66 more
                                                                                                    Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.createListener(StandardContext.java:3391)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadListener(StandardContext.java:5414)
at  com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.loadListener(WebModule.java:1788)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addListener(StandardContext.java:3268)
... 73 more
                        Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.createManagedObject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:329)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.createListenerInstance(WebContainer.java:1015)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.createListenerInstance(WebModule.java:2158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.createListener(StandardContext.java:3389)
... 76 more
                                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.getManager(WeldBootstrap.java:435)
at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.createManagedObject(JCDIServiceImpl.java:320)
at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.createManagedObject(JCDIServiceImpl.java:263)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.managedbean.ManagedBeanManagerImpl.createManagedBean(ManagedBeanManagerImpl.java:485)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.managedbean.ManagedBeanManagerImpl.createManagedBean(ManagedBeanManagerImpl.java:439)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.createManagedObject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:313)
... 79 more
```

**This is constraint xml file**

```
<constraint-definition annotation="org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotNull">
    <validated-by include-existing-validators="true">
        <value>es.project.validator.customConstraint.NotEmptyValidator</value>
    </validated-by>
</constraint-definition>
```

**And validation.xml**

```
<validation-config
xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration validation-configuration-1.0.xsd"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<constraint-mapping>META-INF/validation/mapping.xml</constraint-mapping>
```

**Project's structure**

```
WEB-INF
    +----\classes
          +-------\META-INF
           ------- validation.xml
                     ----------\validation
                               +----------\mapping.xml
```

**Validator code**

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraintvalidation.HibernateConstraintValidatorContext;

public class NotEmptyValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NotNull,Object> {

@Override
public void initialize(NotNull constraintAnnotation) {

}

@Override
public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {


    if(value.toString().isEmpty()){
        ...........
                    ...........
                    ...........
    }

    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

In your case the problem is that you are referencing `org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotNull` but you probably want `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull`. Your `mapping.xml` should look like this:

```
<constraint-definition annotation="javax.validation.constraints.NotNull">
    <validated-by include-existing-validators="true">
        <value>es.project.validator.customConstraint.NotEmptyValidator</value>
    </validated-by>
</constraint-definition>
```

The other parts of your configuration should be correct. **This should work without defining the annotation.**

If you want to implement a custom Bean Validation validator without replacing/reusing an existent one, you need a annotation definition and you have to implement the [ConstraintValidator interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidator.html). Here is an example:

The annotation:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;  
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;  
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;  
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;  
import java.lang.annotation.Target;  
import javax.validation.Constraint;  

@Documented  
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)  
@Target({ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR,ElementType.PARAMETER,ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})  
@Constraint(validatedBy=NotNulllValidator.class)  
public @interface NotNull {  

   String message();  
   Class[] groups() default {};  
   Class[] payload() default {};  
}
```

The validator:

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class NotNulllValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NotNull, String> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(NotNull email) {}

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String email, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The mapping should stay as you already have it.

**See also:**

- [bean-validation validation.xml ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701482/bean-validation-validation-xml-ignored)
- [how to create a ConstraintValidator for List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865209/how-to-create-a-constraintvalidator-for-list)

Comment: I have edited question adding validator/constraint code. So if I'm right...I coudn't use javax.validation.constraints, isn't? Because my idea was to replace NotNull constraint without declaring a new NotNull constraint.This behaviour will be possible? Or your answer it's the only way??

Comment: Works properly! Only a comment, if you set "@Constraint(validatedBy=NotNulllValidator.class)" throw a exception with message: defines multiple validators for the type. So I think you must omit to change line for "defines multiple "@Constraint(validatedBy={})"